# How to select rows with condition? sql, select sentence

Tags: sql, select, sas, sentence

I have table like this:

```
NAME      IDENTIFICATIONR   SCORE
JOHN         DB              10
JOHN         IT             NULL
KAL          DB              9
HENRY        KK              3
KAL          DB              10
HENRY        IP              9
ALI          IG              10
ALI          PA              9
```

And with select sentence I want that my result would be like only those names whose scores are 9 or above. So basically it means, that, for exaple, Henry cannot be selected, because he has score under the value of 9  in one line , but in the other he has the score of 3 (null values also should be emitted).
My newtable should look like this:

```
NAME 
KAL 
ALI
```

I'm using a sas program. THANK YOU!!

Comment: You should specify your RDBMS system. (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) also in your example output, why is John not included

Comment: John is not included, because in the second line he has the value null, and I want to pick only those whose all scores are 9 or above.

Comment: Please share your attempts - what do you mean by a "select sentence"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COUNT of names will be <> COUNT of scores if there is a missing score.  Requesting equality in the `having` clause will ensure no person with a missing score is in your result set.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select distinct name from have
  group by name
  having count(name) = count(score) and min(score) >= 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select NAME from YOUR_TABLE_NAME name where SCORE > 9 and score is not null
```

Comment: But with this code, john is also selected, though he has null in the second row

Comment: yes. hence my comment above. It wasn't clear to me that was the same John

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

here the solution

```
select name 
from table name where score >= 9 
and score <> NULL;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select name
from table t
group by name
having sum(case when (score < 9  or score is null) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you want full rows then you can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.name = t.name and (t1.score < 9 or t1.score is null)
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be treated `NULL` scores as a value less than `9`.  You can also just use `coalesce()` with `min()`:

```
  select name
  from have
  group by name
  having min(coalesce(score, 0)) >= 9;
```

Note that `select distinct` is almost never useful with `group by` -- and SAS `proc sql` probably does not optimize it well.